# Setting a default constructor for one type with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. `Derived` inherits all `Base`'s constructors. Also, I have a template class `Printer<T>` which holds a reference to an object of type `T` and has a method `print()` which prints an object somehow. Here is a minimal illustration.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}
    int x;
};

template<typename T>
class Printer {
public:
    const T& object;

    Printer(const T& object) : object(object) {}

    void print() {
        cout << object << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Derived& d) {
    return out << d.x;
}

int main() {
    Derived d(1);

    Printer<Derived>(d).print();
}
```

Now I'd like to avoid direct usage of `Printer` and allow such syntax: `Derived d(1); d.print();`. Thus I tried to inherit `Derived` also from `Printer<Derived>`.

```
class Derived : public Base, public Printer<Derived> {
public:
    typedef Printer<Derived> MyPrinter;

    using Base::Base;

    Derived() : MyPrinter(*this) {}
};
```

Now I have a problem: `Base` constructors know nothing about `Printer` and thus cannot initialize it in any way. I also cannot use a constructor delegation here because the constructor which is used in `Derived` is actually inherited from `Base`.

Can I somehow make the default constructor of `Derived` be delegated by any other constructor, even inherited ones? Or maybe there is some other patterns to initialize the second base in multiple inheritance?

One more thing which hardens everything is that I don't have access to `Base`'s code and only can use it as is.

**UPDATE**
On Remy Lebeau's answer: `Base` can have multiple constructors which I'm not aware of (it is a template class as well), so I can't implement all of them and must use `using Base::Base` idiom.

On krzaq's answer: `Printer` actually also has many methods, not only `print()`, so implementing a forwarder class is a nuisance and I try to avoid it.

Comment: You're forgetting about the virtual destructors in your base classes.

Comment: Nope. A constructor can be delegated only by another constructor of the same class. And this has nothing to do with constructors either. Even if somehow constructors can be delegated, the fact is that `Base`'s interface is etched in stone. It is what it is. If, as you say, you can only use `Base` "as is", then the only thing you can do is override any methods in `Base` that are virtual. You cannot add any methods to it. The End.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sure, there are ones in a real code, I just forgot some while making this artificial example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to have access to `Derived` instance from `Printer<Derived>` then you can simply cast it down:

```
template<typename T>
class Printer {
public:
    const T& object;

    Printer() : object(static_cast<T&>(*this)) {}

    void print() {
        cout << object << endl;
    }
};
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/fma3PAqJLnZ10Mog)

or make away with the reference altogether and make your class eligible for [EBO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo):

```
template<typename T>
class Printer {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << static_cast<T&>(*this) << endl;
    }
};
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kYSIztnZrleskomO)

If you can't/don't want to touch `Printer` either, I'd create a separate template `PrinterForwarder` to firward the `print()` call to the right printer:

```
template<typename T>
class PrinterForwarder
{
public:
    void print() {
        Printer<T>(static_cast<T&>(*this)).print();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base, public PrinterForwarder<Derived> {
public:
    using Base::Base;
};
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BAkoEeRbxtYXPq3R)

Comment: `Printer` is not always used in this way, it could also be used as a standalone class (as in the first example) and thus `static_cast` would fail. Maybe I can check with a `dynamic_cast<T&>` where the inheritance really takes place, I'll try it.

Comment: Okay, I thought the first example was somewhat a workaround that you wanted to get rid of. If you don't, I think I'd make a separate printer-forwarder that you could derive from, that'd forward `*this` to the printer.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov I edited the answer. Hopefully this will be more helpful.

Comment: `Printer` has several methods, so helper class will have to have them all duplicated.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Okay. Then I think you have to choose between redeclaring `Base`'s constructors and `Printer`'s interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have a problem: Base constructors know nothing about Printer and thus cannot initialize it in any way.

To do what you are attemping, you won't be able to use a `using Base::Base` statement anymore.  You will have to be more explicit about the constructors that `Derived` implements, so they can each initialize the `Printer` base class as needed, eg:

```
class Derived : public Base, public Printer<Derived> {
public:
    typedef Printer<Derived> MyPrinter;

    Derived() : Base(0), MyPrinter(*this) {}
    Derived(int x) : Base(x), MyPrinter(*this) {}
};
```

Or:

```
class Derived : public Base, public Printer<Derived> {
public:
    typedef Printer<Derived> MyPrinter;

    Derived() : Derived(0) {}
    Derived(int x) : Base(x), MyPrinter(*this) {}
};
```

Comment: This seems to be inevitable, but it is not an option as Base has many ctors and I cannot re-implement them all.

Comment: If `Printer`'s constructor requires an input value then all of the constructors in `Derived` must pass a value to it, which means re-implementing all of the constructors as shown above.  But if you redesign `Printer` to not require an input value in its constructor, like krzaq showed, then you don't have to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You may create one variadic template catch-all constructor that will pass arguments to Base and construct Printer as needed, like this

```
class Derived: ... {
   template<typename... Args>
   Derived(Args&&... args): Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...), Printer(*this) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an amazingly simple solution. Let's store in `Printer` a pointer to `T` instead of a reference.

```
template<typename T>
class Printer {
public:
    const T* objectPtr;

    Printer() : objectPtr(nullptr) {}
    Printer(const T& object) : objectPtr(&object) {}

    void print() {
        if (objectPtr) {
            cout << *objectPtr << endl;
        } else {
            cout << static_cast<const T&>(*this) << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

It looks not really safe but making `Printer()` ctor private seems to make the deal.

Comment: Without virtual functions and casts, wouldn't it call wrong operator(for printer, not for T)?

Comment: Sure it would, fixed now. Cast to `T` is of course needed here.

Comment: Note also that copy/move ctors are worth deleting in this case or you'll get funny stuff when you copy Printer part

Comment: You're right again. Though deleting them will result in Derived class being non-copy/movable which is undesired. Maybe the more appropriate solution would be storing `this` pointer at the moment of creation and passing it over in copy/move ctor. I'm still experimenting on it.